# Expansion of Optimisation Function and symbol

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Currently working through non linear programming exercises, i don't understand what this symbol means, with the double brackets followed by the 2 subscript. Also following on from that i don't understand how he one is expected to square the function and arrive at the answer.

Question - 
Let $A \in R^{m×n} $ with $m \geq n$ and $b \in R^n$. Prove:
Point $\bar{x} \in R^n $ is a solution of the unconstrained optimization problem
min$\Vert Ax−b \Vert_{2}, x \in R ^n$,
if and only if $\bar{x}$ is a solution of the system of linear equations
$A^T Ax = A^T b$ .

Solution - 
$$f(x) := \Vert Ax - b \Vert_2 = ( x^T A^T A x - b^Tx-x^TA^Tb +b^Tb)^{1/2} $$
$$= ( x^T A^T A x -2 b^TAx+b^Tb)^{1/2}$$

Comment: $\| z \|_{2}=\sqrt{z_{1}^{2}+z_{2}^{2}+\ldots+z_{n}^{2}}$

Comment: @BrianBorchers Does the 2 subscript represent something? Does it/ Will it ever change to a 3 for example? will this change it to the root 1/3 or z^3?

Comment: Please type out all images. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the subscript 2 is for.  Read up on $p$-norms.

Comment: Thanks @BrianBorchers very useful! Do you have any idea about the expansion.